# ASP.NET Redirect to Https issue - Error 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We have implemented a `https` for our website, so basically what we have made is implement a redirect.

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule - name" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://yourpath" redirectType="youttype" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

The redirect is working ok, but I got an issue. Some of the users has saved in the bookmarks the old path like this `http://applicationName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f` and the redirect is doing this -> `https://applicationName/?ReturnUrl=/` and I get the error you can see below:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You
>   do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

so far what I have tried to fix the issue is add to my appsetting in the web.config some stuff I saw that could solve the problem:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

and Also

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

but I still having the same issue with the redirect. Any idea how can I fix this issue??

Thanks!!

Comment: Is https: //applicationName/?ReturnUrl=/  the correct new path to login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building your URL based on the match rather than statically:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```